# LESS compile error on retina media query

Tags: css, less

I am unable to compile my LESS document because its returning a compile error on for this:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
```

Can anyone see any reason this is happening? I can't see any errors in the code.

**Update**

I am using SimpLESS to compile. I just checked and it uses LESS 1.3.0.

Comment: What is the compile error? They usually tell you what the problem is...

Comment: What version of LESS are you using? It works with 1.3.3.

Comment: What styles do you have inside this rule? There should be another rules but you cannot write styles immediately in the media query. Just notice.

Comment: This might be your problem: (min-resolution: 2dppx) What you wanted to write there dpi or px? Try to correct that.

Comment: @Caelea dppx is a valid unit (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#resolution).  If LESS is choking on that, then it is a problem with LESS itself.

Comment: @BenM - No compile error, just says syntax error on this line.

Comment: @freejosh - Just updated my post, 1.3.0, SimpLESS doesn't appear to have updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a version issue. When checked on the various versions [here](http://less2css.org/), it has ***no issues*** from LESS 1.3.1+. However, for 1.3.0 it appears to choke at three points:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
  only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
  only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), //<-HERE on the 2/1
  only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
  only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), //<-HERE on the dpi
  only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) //<-HERE on the dppx
{ 
  .test { color: red;}
}
```