# LESS Compile Error With Media Query on older versions

Tags: css, compilation, less

I am brand new to LESS. I am using some code built by another developer.

In the .less file, when I go to compile, it is throwing a parse error on this line:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width: @menu-break-point){


}
```

It doesn't seem to like that selector.

I have read up quite a bit on compilation errors and found out that older versions of LESS don't support this, and that seems to be the problem. This page...

[LESS compile error on retina media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876376/less-compile-error-on-retina-media-query)

...mentions that it requires LESS 1.3.1+, and the SimpLESS compiler I'm using seems to use 1.3.0. Similarly, I have had tried using the the latest versions of SimpLESS App itself, and it still isn't working.

Can someone suggest a local Mac compiler that will use LESS 1.3.1 or above?  I apologize if this seems like a dumb question, but I am new to working with LESS and with compiling software in general. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried installing nodejs and using `npm` to install `less` (which will get the latest version), and then using the vanilla `lessc` compiler to compile it? The instructions are pretty simple, and are on the [LESS website](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: Check out [codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/).

Comment: it doesnt seems to me the same case of the retina media query, what is the compile error?, normally is detailed

Comment: Santiago: The compile error is vague and seemingly. "Syntax Error on line 1." But it's not on line 1. Everything works if I take out the line in question. 
AJP & Fabrico: I am looking into these options and will let you know what I find out.

Comment: if you are compiling minified will be allways at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These were probably all good suggestions, guys, so thank you. But I found out what the problem was in my case, anyway. It was that line, but it was the return in it. In other words, this crashed the compile:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width: @menu-break-point){


}
```

But this did not.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: @menu-break-point){


}
```

This I figured out after having tried Koala, SimLess, CodeKit, Crunch, and other compilers. All doing the same thing when it got to that line. I should have checked that earlier, but I was stuck on the idea that it was the @media query.

Again, I didn't write the .less code I'm working with and this was my first venture into .less.

Answer (score 0):

@menu-break-point is a variable, what is the value of it?

---

My original answer was that the compiler is breaking because cant find the variable  `@menu-break-point` as you mentioned you were new and you got the code from previous, then i preferred to ask the value on it

---

from http://lesscss.org/#reference

> CSS escaping similar to ~"value" syntax. It expects string as a
>   parameter and return its content as is, but without quotes. It can be
>   used to output CSS value which is either not valid CSS syntax, or uses
>   proprietary syntax which LESS doesn�t recognize.

I just tried this three ways and compiled well in my nodejs lessc 1.5.1 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]

```
@menu-break-point: ~"640px";
@media only screen and (min-width: @menu-break-point){
  body{
    background-color:black;
  }
}
@menu-break-point: 640px;
@media only screen and (min-width: @menu-break-point){
  body{
    background-color:black;
  }
}
@menu-break-point: 640px;
@thisSelector: ~"only screen and (min-width: @{menu-break-point})";
@media @thisSelector{
  body{
    background-color:black;
  }
}
```

compiled to

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  body {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  body {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  body {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

I think you could try the third one and see if it works, if not, I recommend you install less nodejs and watchcompile, is what i use.

---

For your comment substraction question:

```
@a:'640px - 1px';
@b:640px - 1px;
@c:~'640px - 1px';

div{ width:@a}
div{ width:@b}
div{ width:@c}
```

compiles to

```
div {
  width: '640px - 1px';
}
div {
  width: 639px;
}
div {
  width: 640px - 1px;
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I know is downvoted but it really seems to me this is the answer

Comment: Hi, Santiago. @menu-break-point is defined earlier in the .less document like so:
 `@menu-break-point: 640px;`

Comment: Hi Steve... can you try to define it like @menu-break-point: ~"640px"; and see how goes?

Comment: Santiago, I will try this later to see if it makes a difference. I also had a problem with a math equation that used 'px' in the var value. Trying to subtract the initials developer's 640px and 1px did not return 639px; it returned a string of '640px - 1px', which is what I'd expect, actually, but figured that maybe .less was different than my, you know, expectations. :) So, I am quite curious: what's the difference between declaring it as the initial developer did and using the ~"value" concept you suggested?